# How to have two different custom scrollbar on one page?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So what I am trying to have is a different scrollbar for the scrollable div and a different one for the whole window. This is what I have tried to do but I haven't been able to get two different colour scroll bar.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'segoe ui light';
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background: #efefef;
}
.container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}
h1{
 padding: 20px 0;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'segoe ui light';
 text-align: center;
}
h2{
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
}
figure{
 top: 0;
 width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 125px;
}
img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.section{
 padding: 50px 0;
 height: 500px;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap:20px;
}
.intro{
 font-weight: 1000;
}
.content{
 max-height: 250px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

/******************SCROLL BAR***********************/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #d2edda;
    //-border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #0b602f;
}

::selection {
    color: white;
    background: #13DA69;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..//css/interview.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <header></header>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>INTERVIEW</h1>
  <div class="section one">
   <h2>Name</h2>
   <div class="intro">
   <b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus laboriosam quia, dolores impedit autem consequuntur eaque sed harum adipisci quos voluptas, maxime ducimus nemo id et excepturi temporibus, <br>perspiciatis reprehenderit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem sed aut dolore magni corrupti. Debitis minus officiis magni, laborum! Unde impedit similique delectus voluptatibus necessitatibus a atque, debitis dolores nulla.</b>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
   </div>
   <figure>
    <img src="" alt="insert img here">
   </figure>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So a different scrollbar for the div and a different scrollbar for the window is required.

Comment: i think, that html/css aproach isnt supported well, you should look after some js

Comment: @Pepo_rasta If you provide some reference code or a link for the same it would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with any CSS selector, you simply need to apply the various `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-elements to the `div` element itself by specifying this within the selector:

```
/* This styles any scrollbar. */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  ...
}

/* This styles any scrollbar which is part of a `div` element. */
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  ...
}
```

---

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'segoe ui light';
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background: #efefef;
}
.container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}
h1{
 padding: 20px 0;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'segoe ui light';
 text-align: center;
}
h2{
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
}
figure{
 top: 0;
 width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 125px;
}
img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.section{
 padding: 50px 0;
 height: 500px;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap:20px;
}
.intro{
 font-weight: 1000;
}
.content{
 max-height: 250px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

/******************SCROLL BAR***********************/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #d2edda;
    //-border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #0b602f;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: red;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background: purple;
}

::selection {
    color: white;
    background: #13DA69;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..//css/interview.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <header></header>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>INTERVIEW</h1>
  <div class="section one">
   <h2>Name</h2>
   <div class="intro">
   <b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus laboriosam quia, dolores impedit autem consequuntur eaque sed harum adipisci quos voluptas, maxime ducimus nemo id et excepturi temporibus, <br>perspiciatis reprehenderit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem sed aut dolore magni corrupti. Debitis minus officiis magni, laborum! Unde impedit similique delectus voluptatibus necessitatibus a atque, debitis dolores nulla.</b>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi laboriosam enim maiores placeat, ullam explicabo magnam. Quam repudiandae fugiat, incidunt explicabo quis amet cupiditate quos dolores tempore maxime distinctio inventore.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate debitis, a saepe eius laboriosam hic incidunt eum ipsam fugiat necessitatibus modi accusantium dignissimos doloribus, adipisci voluptas alias harum molestias officia!</p>
   </div>
   <figure>
    <img src="" alt="insert img here">
   </figure>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```